# Update columns with Null values

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-update

I tried updating a table as follows:

```
update userloginstats set logouttime = sysdate where logouttime = null;
```

It didn't update the columns with null values. What went wrong?

Comment: <resisting temptation to add yet another answer that says exactly the same thing...>

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Change it to

```
...where logouttime is null;
                    ^^^^^^^
```

`NULL` is a special value and we cannot use the usual `=` operator with it.

From the [Oracle documentation for NULL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm):

> To test for nulls, use **only** the comparison conditions IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result depends on the value of the null, then the result is UNKNOWN because null represents a lack of data, a null **cannot** be equal or unequal to any value or to another null

Answer (score 11):

You cannot compare NULLs with =.

Use this:

```
update userloginstats set logouttime= sysdate where logouttime is null;
```

Answer (score 7):

`logouttime is null`, not `= null`.  `null` is never equal to anything, not even itself.  Thus, the operator `is`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `is null` not `= null`

```
update userloginstats set logouttime= sysdate where logouttime is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

For nulls you must use "**IS NULL**" or "**IS NOT NULL**" rather than the = operator. This is because null is technically neither true or false, rather it's the absence of a value either way.

Most programming languages typically associate null with false for convenience (and thereby enabling the use of the = operator), but SQL takes a more purist approach, rightly or wrongly.