# Update Column value for all rows in Table where Column Value Is Null?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, toad

Still learning SQL-Fu, and trying to figure out how to do a simple update on my Table (ex. [TABLE1])to where all rows that have a `[COST]` column value of `NULL` are updated to a `[COST]` value of `0.00`.

Can anyone show me how this is properly done? I've found examples for how to update EVERY row value for the column, but haven't quite been able to piece together the WHERE condition in a functional way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update columns with Null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923721/update-columns-with-null-values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test for a NULL value in a column using `IS NULL`.

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET cost = 0
    WHERE cost IS NULL;
```