# Oracle: How to retrieve a NULL row

Tags: oracle10g

I tried to extract the row which doesn't have any value in the timestamp column.

`select * from user_details where lastlogin_time = null;`

Comment: [To test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions IS NULL and IS NOT NULL.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Nulls.htm#SQLRF30037)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update columns with Null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923721/update-columns-with-null-values)